# What does a p-value of exactly 1.0000 mean?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

I have a table of pairwise comparisons using paired t-tests, which I produced using the following code in R:

```
with(d_OAI, pairwise.t.test(OAI, Ven,p.adjust.method="bonferroni", paired=T))
```

Some of the p-values are significant (i.e. less than 0.05) and some are not. However, several of the p-values equal 1.00000. I assume this means the two things are definitely NOT significantly different, but is this R rounding up from 0.9999 or is a p-value of 1.000 meaningful?

Comment: To be certain of the cause in this case it would be best to have the data.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not exactly familiar with the specific R functions, but if there's a Bonferroni correction, I believe that is likely to be the explanation. For example, suppose you tested two hypotheses and got unadjusted p = 0.6, 0.6. The simplistic Bonferroni adjustment would be 1.2, 1.2, but since these are not valid probabilities, it would truncate these to 1.0 and 1.0.

Comment: But I thought the question is about p-value for the paired t-test?

Comment: yes, but it appears that the p-values are being adjusted for multiple comparisons.

Comment: @CliffAB Exploring the source code using `stats:::p.adjust` confirms your belief about the function truncating p-values.

Answer (score 9):

If the data are discrete it's possible to get an exact p-value of 1 on a paired t-test, when the mean difference is exactly 0.

Otherwise, yes, a value just less than 1 may be shown as 1 at some given number of significant figures.

Comment: Isn't t-test meant for continuous data? Why discrete suddenly?

Comment: @StudentT While the test is supposed to be used on data drawn from a normal distribution, that doesn't stop people *applying* it to observations that are discrete values, such as exam marks or sums of Likert-scale items or IQs, for example. The question was not about what is assumed when deriving the distribution of the statistic, but what it might mean when a p-value of 1 happened with a particular data set (which data set is not itself supplied). One possible cause is discrete data resulting in a mean difference of exactly 0; if so, there's nothing further to explain.

Answer (score 3):

@Cliff-ab already provided a right answer. In case you want to get further insight on the meaning of the obtained p-values, making a histogram out of them (before correcting for multiple testing) may be of help.

In particular, as nicely described by @david-robinson in http://varianceexplained.org/statistics/interpreting-pvalue-histogram/, p-values close to 1.0 may indicate that you have been applying a one-sided test when maybe you wanted a two-sided test or may be caused by missing values in your data, distorting the results of the test. Another option (as @Cliff-AB mentions) is the Bonferroni correction that you are applying, which seems the most plausible cause.